# Downloading project from GitHub

Tags: github, download

I am trying to install Pocketsphinx for Android on Linux. I am following [this](http://swathiep.blogspot.in/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html) tutorial.

In step 4 of the project in says to download a project from github. [This](https://github.com/cjac/cmusphinx/tree/trunk/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo) is the link to that project. However there no Download.zip button in that page. How to download that project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the tree of the project. Head over to the [root of the repo](https://github.com/cjac/cmusphinx) & you'll find the zip

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can download from project main page
https://github.com/cjac/cmusphinx

1. click Download ZIP button
2. UNZIP
3. extract PocketSphinxAndroidDemo folder